# imagettftext вывод текста на картинку php

Tags: php, html, изображения, text

Здраствуйте, у меня возник вопрос.

Я подобрал картинку и вывел текст на неё. НО текст иногда может заходить за границы картинки, тем самым пропадает  часть текста, пример текста:

```
"Приходит мужик в ресторан и заказывает ведро помоев, ну официанты  
  на уши приносят ему то что он заказал ну и смотрят.  А  мужик  берет  
  седает ведерко и делает заказ там бифштекс, салатику, коньячку и т.д. 
  Hу тут  уже официанты не выдержали и спрашиваю:
     - Простите, но зачем вам понадобилось седать ведро помоев перед 
     всем этим?"
```

и код обработчик:

```
  //Set the Content Type
  header('Content-type: image/png');

  // Create Image From Existing File
  $jpg_image = imagecreatefrompng('imgdf/backfun.png');

  // Allocate A Color For The Text
  $white = imagecolorallocate($jpg_image, 0, 0, 0);

  // Set Path to Font File
  $font_path = 'font1.ttf';

  // Set Text to Be Printed On Image
  $text = " Приходит мужик в ресторан и заказывает ведро помоев, ну официанты  
  на уши приносят ему то что он заказал ну и смотрят.  А  мужик  берет  
  седает ведерко и делает заказ там бифштекс, салатику, коньячку и т.д. 
  Hу тут  уже официанты не выдержали и спрашиваю:
     - Простите, но зачем вам понадобилось седать ведро помоев перед 
     всем этим?";

  // Print Text On Image
  imagettftext($jpg_image, 20, 0, 10, 100, $white, $font_path, $text);

  // Send Image to Browser
  imagepng($jpg_image);

  // Clear Memory
  imagedestroy($jpg_image);
```

### Вопрос:

Картинка имеет размер - 800*480(px)

Как можно ограничить (сделать границы), для выводимого текста, чтобы текст не выезжал за пределы картинки, а чтобы переносился на новую строку?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Можете воспользоваться этим:
https://github.com/NikitchenkoSergey/idg <br />
метод text() вписывает текст в блок, разбивая его на строки по ширине блока.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можете выводить через `<pre>`, для этого храните ваши строчки с нужной длиной.

```
<?php
$text = "
  Приходит мужик в ресторан и заказывает ведро помоев, ну официанты  
  на уши приносят ему то что он заказал ну и смотрят.  А  мужик  берет  
  седает ведерко и делает заказ там бифштекс, салатику, коньячку и т.д. 
  Hу тут  уже официанты не выдержали и спрашиваю:
  - Простите, но зачем вам понадобилось седать ведро помоев перед 
    всем этим?";  
echo "<pre>{$text}</pre>";
```

2) Можете подобрать шрифт и рассчитать нужную длину строки. Брать столько символов и возвращаться назад, искать начало последнего слова, его переносить и брать следующую строку.

3) Просто поставьте jQuery ;D
https://htmler.ru/2013/12/07/jquery-perenosy-russkogo-teksta/